# Firefox 4: Changed alert behaviour?

Tags: firefox, configuration

Up to Firefox 3.6, when a window which was not active was showing an alert (e.g. because a long running ajax-call returned and is now notifying the user), that window was flashing in the task bar (Windows 7) or it was brought to the top of the window stack (< Window 7).

That behaviour has changed in FF4.

Can I enforce the old behaviour in Javascript? Or is there a setting in about:config which will give me back the old behaviour? I checked, but I didn't find one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

1. Type about:config into the adress bar
2. Filter: prompts.tab_modal.enabled
3. Set the value to false

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to add the answer myself when I found yours :)